# Conditional flag based on Groupby Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to use conditional statements to create flag based on id and precedence order -

Dataframe -

```
    df=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3],
     'var':['Apple','Banana','Orange','Mango', 'Mango', 'Banana','Orange','Mango'],
      'flag':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]})
```

Precedence order -
Apple > Banana > Orange

Conditions -

1 - if Apple, Banana & Mango are present in id then flag for Banana & Ornage becomes 0, there will be no impact on Mango, it will be 1.

2 - If Banana & Orange are present then flag for Orange will become 0

Output -

```
     df=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3],
     'var':['Apple','Banana','Orange','Mango', 'Mango', 'Banana','Orange','Mango'],
      'flag':[1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1]})
```

Method -

I have tried grouping the data and thought of performing the intersection by defining conditional lists.

I believe I have complicated it and doing the wrong way. Please guide.

```
group_test = df.groupby(['id'],as_index=False).var.agg(lambda x: x.unique().tolist())
list_1 = ['Apple','Banana','Orange']
list_2 = ['Banana', 'Orange']
```

Comment: So 'Mango' should just be left alone?

Comment: It is a sample data, I have a datasets with more fruits.

Comment: Ok. I only asked because your `group_test` does not include 'Mango' at all and yet it is in the data and appear in the groups

Comment: Yes, I choose the bad example, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop through each chunk of the `GroupBy` object and set the `flag` column to the value required where rows meet the certain condition using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

First let's set *all* of our conditions ahead of time.

```
match1 = {'Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango'}
match2 = {'Banana', 'Orange'}
p_cond = (df['var'].str.contains('Banana|Orange', regex=True))
s_cond = (df['var'] == 'Orange')
```

Then we can loop over our grouped object setting the `flag` column if it matches our criteria.

```
for k, v in df.groupby('id')['var']:
    vals = set(v)
    id_cond = (df['id'] == k)

    if vals.issuperset(match1):
        df.loc[id_cond & p_cond, 'flag'] = 0
    elif vals.issuperset(match2):
        df.loc[id_cond & s_cond, 'flag'] = 0
    else:
        continue
```

This yields us the following results.

```
   flag  id     var
0     1   1   Apple
1     0   1  Banana
2     0   1  Orange
3     1   1   Mango
4     1   2   Mango
5     1   3  Banana
6     0   3  Orange
7     1   3   Mango
```

Comment: It is working, I like the way you have approached the problem. I can easily manipulate the code based on the conditions. Thank you @gold_cy

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that works with the given data. I don't think it would work if you had orders on `(n-2)` of the categories where `n =` number of categories.

This is a more general answer if you want to identify the **Highest Category** for each `id`

Edit: If you have a small set of categories that dictate the ordering, simply lump them together into an `other` category which can be assigned the last order. That should be enough

```py
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3],
     'var':['Apple','Banana','Orange','Mango', 'Mango', 'Banana','Orange','Mango'],
      'flag':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]})

# create a categorical array with the orders set this way.
# this keeps the ordering Apple > Banana > Orange > Mango
df['category'] = pd.Categorical(df['var'], ordered=True, categories=reversed(['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Mango']))

# group by id and just get a boolean of whether var = max category
# for each id subset, compare each var to the maximum category in that subset
df['highest_level'] = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda df_: 1 * (df_['var'] == df_['category'].max())).reset_index(drop=True)

# put mango back to 1 - since Mango was the lowest in the order
# the only times Mango would have a highest_level = 1 would be
# when the entire subset only has Mango var
df.loc[df['var'] == 'Mango', 'highest_level'] = 1
```

Comment: not very readable in my opinion. can you explain what is going on at least with more than just comments? this will help beginners and other readers alike.

Comment: The data I have contains 40 different categories, as you suggested, it will not work for higher n.

Comment: :) There is a rather simple remedy for that. You could create a column where all categories that do not apply to the condition are set to 'others' for example. So Mango, Apricot etc. could be 'others' and your categorical variable can take that into account